# Hibernate query syntax error?

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
from (From FlightSchedule as a where a.route.routeId=1) as b
```

What is wrong in above query?
It gives me this error

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 6 [from
 (From FlightSchedule as a where a.route.routeId=1) as b]
```

I have tried to write it in different ways but that don't work.
What I suppose is that the inner query should evaluate to a list of objects and the same should be returned by the first `from` token?
Please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: How does your whole query look like? change the From to from, they are case sensitive.

Comment: IN mysql This should be like this:
select * from (select * from FlightSchedule where routeId=1) a;

Comment: Why are using nested queries here? By the way if you want nested queries, the nested query shall contain `select` clause, and as far as I know you can't use nested queries in `from` clause in hibernate.

Comment: Why not just `From FlightSchedule as a where a.route.routeId=1`?

Comment: because I am going to do self join.
select * from (select * from flightschedule where routeId=1) join (select * from flightschedule where routeId=2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumptions are wrong. This is invalid HQL. Quote from [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries):

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But how can I write HQL equivalent to
select * from (select * from FlightSchedule where routeId=1) a;

Comment: I tried that too but now it says unexpected token *.
Also I don't find any select * example on the documentation page.

Comment: You can't. subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses. Use SQL.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet. But with sql I will not get benefit of hibernate cache.Can I?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just as with HQL queries. SQLQuery extends Query, which has a setCacheable() method